# Update MongoDB collection based on values from an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have a MongoDB collection which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "stock": "GOOGLE",
    "price": 0
  },
  {
    "stock": "FACEBOOK",
    "price": 0
  }
]
```

I have a `Stock_Prices` **object** like this:

```
{
  "GOOGLE": {
    "price": 31.35
  },
  "FACEBOOK": {
    "price": 10.75
  }
}
```

I need to update each stock in the collection from the `Stock_Prices` object using Node.js.

I have thought of the following approach:

- Iterate over collection documents
- For each document, get the "stock" field value (GOOGLE, FACEBOOK)
- Extract the price from the `Stock_Prices[document.stock].price`
- Update the document

This is an unacceptable approach because I have thousands and thousands of records and update is needed on an immediate basis.

> Update: not necessary, it should be an update operation - if it's a lookup then also will do the work I believe

How do I do it?

Comment: Cannot you loop through `Stock_Prices` keys and update each document without retrieve all documents like this: `YourModel.updateOne(stock, { price })`?

Comment: What difference will it make? I'm still updating one by one.

Comment: The last statement in your updated quote is still not quite clear to me. Do you want to update or it's OK to have an aggregation output?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to take your **object** and convert it to an array and pass it to the aggregation pipeline.

```
const stocksMap = {
  "GOOGLE": {
    "price": 31.35
  },
  "FACEBOOK": {
    "price": 10.75
  }
}

const stocks = Object.entries(stocksMap).map(([stock, price]) => ({ stock, price : price.price }))

/* You will get something like this
[{
  "stock": "GOOGLE",
  "price": 31.35
}, {
  "stock": "FACEBOOK",
  "price": 10.75
}]
*/

/* If you want to just read the data, without updating */

db.stocks.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      price: {
        $reduce: {
          input: stocks,
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.stock", "$stock"] },
              "$$this.price",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

/* If you want to update the existing data, you can use the same pipeline in an aggregation (available from v4.2) */

db.stocks.update({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      price: {
        $reduce: {
          input: stocks,
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.stock", "$stock"] },
              "$$this.price",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If you don't want to get the documents updated, you can put `stocks` in another collection and use `$lookup` instead. That should be more performant.

Comment: This is some monster query. Thanks! I'll check this out!

Answer (score 0):

I will take one stock object from the post  and show how to update:

```
var stock_price =  { "GOOGLE": { "price": 31.35 } }  // this is the input

var stock_price_doc = Object.keys(stock_price).map (k => ( {field: k, value: stock_price[k] } ) )[0]
```

`stock_price_doc` has this value now: `{ "field" : "GOOGLE", "value" : { "price" : 31.35 } }`

The collection's document (from the post):

```
{
    "stock": "GOOGLE",
    "price": 0
}
```

The update operation:

```
db.stocks.update(
  { stock: stock_price_doc.field },
  { $set: { price: stock_price_doc.value.price } }
)
```

The updated document (result):

```
{ "stock" : "GOOGLE", "price" : 31.35 }
```

In case the update is to *increment* the stock price, instead of a *setting* the value use this:

```
{ $inc: { price: stock_price_doc.value.price } }
```

Comment: appreciate it but still, I will have to create `stock_price_doc` for each company right? It's still one by one / step by step process right?

Comment: There are different approaches you can try. One way is, you can create an array of the objects, iterate over them and process each element of the array and update one at a time. This will be many trips to the server. To avoid these trips, you can use the [Bulk Write Operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/index.html) (look for bulk update) which sends all the updates to the server in bulk (and this will be an efficient operation).